# Simple htaccess issue. How do we configure this rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sorry if this seems elementary, I haven't been able to fuse the various topics into a script that works.

I need to ensure that all traffic be it

```
http:// https:// http://www. https://www.
```

becomes

```
http://domain.com
```

with the exception of one folder which I need to be exclusively

```
https://domain.com/specialfolder
```

In any case I want "www" to be removed.

This is what I am currently using:

```
# Redirect www urls to non-www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I would be so grateful if someone would kindly show me how this .htaccess should be written.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this to work-

```
# Redirect www urls to non-www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http:/domain.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# turn off ssl across the board
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=off
RewriteRule ^/?(/) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# turn it back on for special folders
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(specialfolder) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Thanks Anyways :D